# UI gets hangs on while reading a port

Tags: c#, sockets

I am reading from a Ethernet port using the following code:

```
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();

class ClsReadPort
    {

    public void Connect()
        {
            try
            {
                clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
                if (!clientSocket.Connected)
                {
                    clientSocket.Connect("192.168.0.25", 1324);
                }
              }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               MsgBox(ex.Message)

            }
        }

        public string Capture()
        {
            try
            {
                if (clientSocket.Connected)
                {
                   NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                        byte[] inStream = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize + 1];
                        serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, Convert.ToInt32(clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize));
                        string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);

                        oCapture = returndata;
                 }
              }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
             MsgBox(ex.Message)
            }
        }
}
```

In my main program for updating the reading values:

```
ClsReadPort objRead = new ClsReadPort();

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
txtReadValue.Value = objRead.Capture();
}
```

It is working fine. But when ever the Ethernet cable disconnects, the entire UI gets hanged. Its stays on this line:

```
serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, Convert.ToInt32(clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize));
```

How to do it as parallel task without affecting the UI??

Answer (score 1):

In .net 4.5 you could use the [async methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh194211.aspx) and await them
For Async have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/hh156513.aspx)

Here is a also a [Async Socket Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx) without await form MSDN

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dispatcher to start your Capture task in separate thread

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
{  
    try
    {       
        txtReadValue.Value = objRead.Capture();   
    }
    catch { } 
}
```

Comment: i am running it on timer of 1 sec. Is it OK?

Comment: @Olivarsham Well, no it's not. You have a clientSocket member, and you would have the thread problems with sharing it and probably several threads running, which modify your txtReadValue.Value. You have to rewrite your code to use Monitor locking with some var or checking your action state, in order to prevent from creating new threads before previous are unfinished.